# html input custom error shakes display on devices iphone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, vue.js, quasar-framework

I made a box-shaped input like an OTP code input, and I input it but the display when I input shakes

To see visit this link https://youtu.be/qbFNLUZkrp8

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @ivan my code is in the new answer on bottom

Answer (score 0):

my code
--html--

```html
<div class="col-12 row">
  <div class="col-12 row justify-start" style="font-weight:700;">
      <p class="col-12" style="margin-bottom:unset;">Your Mobile number</p>
      <p style="margin-bottom:unset;" class="sub-label">Example: 91234567</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 row">
    <div class="col-12 justify-center">    
      <input 
        id="mobile1"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile1"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile1, $event, $refs.mobile2)"
        ref="mobile1"
        autofocus
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile2"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile2"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile1, $event, $refs.mobile3)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile2"
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile3"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile3"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile2, $event, $refs.mobile4)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile3"
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile4"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile4"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile3, $event, $refs.mobile5)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile4"
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile5"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile5"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile4, $event, $refs.mobile6)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile5"
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile6"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile6"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile5, $event, $refs.mobile7)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile6"
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile7"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile7"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile6, $event, $refs.mobile8)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile7"
      >
      <input 
        id="mobile8"
        type="number"
        pattern="\d*"
        v-model="mobile8"
        class="modifyInput"
        maxlength="1"
        size="1"
        oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
        @keyup="jump($refs.mobile7, $event, $refs.mobile8)"
        @focus="onBoxFocus($event)"
        ref="mobile8"
      > 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

--javascript--

```
jump (before, event, next) {
  // console.log('this[event.target.id]', this[event.target.id])
  // console.log('this.beforeFocus: ', this.beforeFocus)
  event.preventDefault()
  if (this.$q.platform.is.platform === 'iphone') {
    if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
      if (this[event.target.id] === '' && this.beforeFocus) {
        // before.focus()
        setTimeout(() => before.focus(), 0)
        this.beforeFocus = false
      } else {
        if (this[event.target.id] === '') {
          this.beforeFocus = true
        }
      }
      if (next === event.target && this.pinLast) {
        this.pinLast = false
      }
    } else if ((event.keyCode >= 48) && (event.keyCode <= 57) && (event.code <= 'KeyA')) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      // next.focus()
      setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
    } else if (event.keyCode === 229) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      if (event.target.value) {
        // next.focus()
        setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
      if (this[event.target.id] === '' && this.beforeFocus) {
        // before.focus()
        setTimeout(() => before.focus(), 0)
        this.beforeFocus = false
      } else {
        if (this[event.target.id] === '') {
          this.beforeFocus = true
        }
      }
      // console.log('this.beforeFocus: ', this.beforeFocus)
      if (next === event.target && this.pinLast) {
        this.pinLast = false
      }
    } else if ((event.keyCode >= 48) && (event.keyCode <= 57) && (event.code <= 'KeyA')) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      // next.focus()
      setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
    } else if (event.keyCode === 229) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      if (event.target.value) {
        next.focus()
        setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
      }
    }
  }
},
jumpAphabet (before, event, next) {
  // event.preventDefault()
  // console.log('this[event.target.id]', this[event.target.id])
  // console.log('this.beforeFocus: ', this.beforeFocus)
  if (this.$q.platform.is.platform === 'iphone') {
    if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
      if (this[event.target.id] === '' && this.beforeFocus) {
        // before.focus()
        setTimeout(() => before.focus(), 0)
        this.beforeFocus = false
      } else {
        if (this[event.target.id] === '') {
          this.beforeFocus = true
        }
      }
      // console.log('this.beforeFocus: ', this.beforeFocus)
      // if (next === event.target && this.pinLast) {
      //   this[event.target.id] = ''
      //   this.pinLast = false
      // } else {
      //   this[before.id] = ''
      //   before.focus()
      // }
      if (next === event.target && this.pinLast) {
        this.pinLast = false
      }
    } else if ((event.keyCode >= 65) && (event.keyCode <= 90)) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      // next.focus()
      setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
    } else if (event.keyCode === 229) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      if (event.target.value) {
        // next.focus()
        setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
      if (this[event.target.id] === '' && this.beforeFocus) {
        // before.focus()
        setTimeout(() => before.focus(), 0)
        this.beforeFocus = false
      } else {
        if (this[event.target.id] === '') {
          this.beforeFocus = true
        }
      }
      // console.log('this.beforeFocus: ', this.beforeFocus)
      // if (this.beforeFocus) {
      //   before.focus()
      //   this.beforeFocus = false
      // }
      // if (next === event.target && this.pinLast) {
      //   this[event.target.id] = ''
      //   this.pinLast = false
      // } else {
      //   this[before.id] = ''
      //   before.focus()
      // }
      if (next === event.target && this.pinLast) {
        this.pinLast = false
      }
    } else if ((event.keyCode >= 65) && (event.keyCode <= 90)) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      // next.focus()
      setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
    } else if (event.keyCode === 229) {
      if (next === event.target) {
        this.pinLast = true
        this.beforeFocus = false
      }
      if (event.target.value) {
        // next.focus()
        setTimeout(() => next.focus(), 0)
      }
    }
  }
},
```